# Uso de this con arrays en función constructor de javascript

Tags: javascript

Después de ver bien la teoría me quedaron claros algunos conceptos, sin embargo, según este programa que compara respuestas, me dice que no coordino bien los conceptos. Si me pudieran ayudar a entender el ejercicio les agradezco, soy un noob pero sigo en el proceso de aprender.

Entiendo que el `this.` hace referencia al objeto, pero como dice el ejercicio que las dos últimas propiedades son arrays, coloqué también `this.` Pero bueno, estoy seguro que es solo ordenar bien los conceptos. ¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?

```
function crearClasePersona() {
  // Crear una clase para construir objeto de tipo Persona.
  // el constructor debe recibir:
  // nombre (string) , edad (integer) , hobbies (array de strings) , amigos (array de objetos)
  // Esta funcion debe retonar la clase Persona.

  class Persona {
    constructor() {

    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.edad = edad;
    this.hobbies = this.hobbies;
    this.amigos = this.amigos; 

    }
return Persona;
}
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es el error? ¿Cuál es el código que usas para alimentar la clase? ¿Por qué el constructor no tiene parámetros?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Veamos algunos puntos:

En cuanto al método constructor

- Centrándonos en la clase, podrás notar que el constructor en teoría espera recibir valores para 4 parámetros y digo en teoría por que te hace falta declarar dichos parámetros entre los paréntesis de dicho método, [aqui puedes leer mas](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Classes/constructor).
- Lo anterior a la larga te dará problemas cuando hagas la instancia de la clase en un objeto mas o menos así:

  ```
  const data = new Persona(/*valores.........*/);

  console.log(data);
  ```

Por que generará que que recibas un error como este:

> "ReferenceError: nombre is not defined

En cuanto a `this.hobbies` y `this.amigos`

Esta sintaxis que declaras en el constructor no es correcta:

```
this.hobbies = this.hobbies;
this.amigos = this.amigos;
```

Por que del lado izquierdo de la asignación será una propiedad que usarás y del lado derecho el valor que le asignarás (*que obtendrás cuando en la instancia el usuario pase los argumentos requeridos*), entonces debería lucir así:

```
this.hobbies = hobbies;
this.amigos  = amigos;
```

- Como estás escribiendo en un lenguaje altamente no tipado, entonces al momento no hace diferencia si lo que esperas es un valor primitivo o un objeto o un array:
- No hace sentido que la clase exista dentro de un método o función (*al menos no con el contexto que has provisto*)
- La clase es la que de hecho puede tener métodos declarados para trabajar manipulando las propiedades que tiene declaradas (*estos van a depender de lo que se supone que esperas hacer con los valores ingresados*)

Quedando entonces así:

```js
    class Persona {
      constructor (nombre, edad, hobbies, amigos) {
        this.name = nombre;
        this.edad   = edad;
        this.hobbies = hobbies;
        this.amigos  = amigos;
      }
    }
    
    const data = new Persona('Tu', 20, ['nada', 'nada'], [{clave1: 1, clave2: 2}, {clave1: 1, clave2: 2}]);
    
    console.log(data);
```

- Como notas, es en la instancia de la clase donde ya declaro los valores.
- [Aqui puedes leer mas](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Classes)

Answer (score 1):

Primeramente, la clase `Persona` no debería ir nunca dentro de la función del ejercicio. Una clase es algo así como un molde que debes usar cada vez que necesites un objeto de ese tipo, por tanto debería ser independiente.

Luego, dentro de la función crearás una instancia de la clase, pasándole al constructor los elementos que se te piden en el ejercicio y como se te piden. Tienes un constructor vacío en la clase, debes ponerle los parámetros necesarios.

También debes crear métodos de lectura (he puesto algunos de ejemplo, modifícalos a tu gusto o necesidad).

```js
/* La clase debe ir fuera de la función, no dentro*/
class Persona {
  constructor(nombre, edad, hobbies, amigos) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.edad = edad;
    this.hobbies = hobbies;
    this.amigos = amigos;
  }

  /*getters*/
  getNombre() {
    return this.nombre;
  }

  getEdad() {
    return this.edad;
  }
  
  getHobbies() {
    return this.hobbies.toString();
  }

  getAmigos() {
    let mAmigos = "Amigos:\n";
    for (var p in this.amigos) {
      for (var k in this.amigos[p]) {
        mAmigos += "\t" + this.amigos[p][k] + "\n";
      }
      mAmigos += "\n";
    }

    return mAmigos;
  }


  /*setters*/

  setNombre(nombre) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
  }
  setEdad(edad) {
    this.edad = edad;
  }

  setHobbies(hobbies) {
    this.hobbies = this.hobbies;
  }

  setAmigos(amigos) {
    this.amigos = amigos;
  }

}

/*Este es tu ejercicio*/
function crearClasePersona() {
  /*Creamos una instancia de la clase pasándoles los valores al constructor con new*/

  mPersona = new Persona("Pedro", 23, ["pescar", "leer"], 
  [{
    "nombre": "Pepe",
    "edad": 23
  }, {
    "nombre": "Juana",
    "edad": 22
  }]);
  return mPersona;
}

let laPersona = crearClasePersona();
/*Prueba de algunos métodos*/
console.log(laPersona.getNombre());
console.log(laPersona.getEdad());
console.log(laPersona.getAmigos());
console.log(laPersona.getHobbies());
```

Answer (score 0):

Te falta pasar los parametros en el constructor para que entonces puedas definir todos los parametros de la clase Persona. Buena suerte

NOTA: Que lo que te estan enseñando aqui es como crear `factory functions`, asi que por eso es que no tienes que tender la clase afuera de la funcion, y por eso es que retornas la clase sin la instanciacion.

```
function crearClasePersona() {
    class Persona {
        constructor(nombre, edad, hobbies, amigos) {
            this.nombre = nombre;
            this.edad = edad;
            this.hobbies = hobbies;
            this.amigos = amigos; 
        }
    }

    return Persona;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Prueba esto

```
function crearClasePersona() {
    
    class Persona {
        constructor(nombre, edad, hobbies,amigos) {//escribir el constructor con las atributos que recibirá
          this.nombre = nombre;
          this.edad = edad;
          this.hobbies = hobbies;
        }
    
      }
      
      var andresFelipe = new Persona("andres", 17, ["comer","bailar"]);//asignar una variable con nuevo objeto Persona
      console.log(andresFelipe);//ver el objeto
      return Persona;

}

crearClasePersona();//hechar a andar la función
```